# How would I retrieve multiple rows from an Oracle stored procedure/function in Groovy?

Tags: oracle, groovy

I was wondering if there is a way to return multiple rows from an Oracle stored procedure/function in Groovy?  Normally, you do this by returning  REF CURSOR.  Is there a way to return a REF CURSOR to some calling Groovy and iterating through the records returned? I've looked online and can't seem to find an example or explanation of this.  For example if I have a stored function:

```
create or replace function get_dept_emps(p_deptno in number) 
  return sys_refcursor is
      v_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
      open v_rc for 'select empno, ename, mgr, sal from emp where deptno = :deptno' using p_deptno;
      return v_rc;
end;
```

How would I write the Groovy to call this and iterate through the results?

Comment: Tried http://www.craigburke.com/2011/05/13/oracle-stored-procs-in-grails.html

Comment: I changed it slightly from what he had, but yes, the trick was importing  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.